# Android graphics draw wrong perspective on different api

Tags: android, graphics, perspective

Making an application, I needed to draw a perspective. On api> 27 everything is fine, but on 27 and below weird things! The bottom two points wrong build perspective

```
    float[] srcT = {
            0, 0, // Coordinate of top left point
            0, height, // Coordinate of bottom left point
            wight, height, // Coordinate of bottom right point
            wight, 0  // Coordinate of top right point
    };

    float[] dstT = {
            top_left_x, top_left_y, // Coordinate of top left point
            bottom_left_x, bottom_left_y, // Coordinate of bottom left point
            bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y, // Coordinate of bottom right point
            top_right_x, top_right_y  // Coordinate of top right point
    };

    Shader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    matrix.setPolyToPoly(srcT, 0, dstT, 0, 4);
    shader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
    paint.setShader(shader);
```

it's on 28 api :

[image: image1]

and this is 22 api:

[image: image2]